# How to send SMS programmatically without opening message app

Tags: android

I am new to Android and in my app I want to send an SMS to my phone without opening the existing MessageApp. To achieve this, I wrote the code below, but I am not receiving any messages in my phone.

What is the problem?

### code:

```
private void sendSms(String phoneNo, String msg) {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, I added the permission below to my manifesto file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

Answer (score 4):

you have to import: `import android.telephony.SmsManager;`

Also you need to add runtime permisssion for Api>23

```
if(isSMSPermissionGranted()){
    sendSms(String phoneNo, String msg);
}
```

use this method:

```
    public  boolean isSMSPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 0);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

catch the permission result in:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 0: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //send sms here call your method
                sendSms(String phoneNo, String msg);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
 }
```

Comment: message not receiving to my phone

Comment: did u get any exception in `catch` block?

Comment: no showing like "Message sent" but meessage not reciving to my phone

Comment: try adding `+international phone code` to the phone number

Answer (score 0):

The `sendSMS()` function will be

```
    //---sends an SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    }
```

Hope this Tutorial can help you ! 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this function...

```
String mobileNumber="0123456789";
String messege="Message";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
List<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(messege);

for (String msg : messages)
{
     PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,new   Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
     PendingIntent deliveredIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0,new  Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

     sms.sendTextMessage(personalPhone, null, msg, sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`import android.telephony.SmsManager;`
not `import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;`

This work on my phone. Version 6 + may need permission so please look that and add permission. It will help you.